# Plot a graph with individual years from specific package?

Tags: data-visualization

So I have package wq (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wq/vignettes/wq-package.html) and it has a section to graph decomposed time series:

chl27 <- sfbayChla[, "s27"]
d1 <- decompTs(chl27)
plot(d1, nc = 1, main = "Station 27 Chl-a decomposition")

Is it possible to get the years as increment of one rather that in 5 years batch?

My data has less years, so seeing the exact year would help.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... as you provide no minimal working example, and I do not seem to be able to download the example data from the vignette you link to (or to try and create a sample dataset by hand), I have to improvise a bit.

The graphs in the vignette look like `wq` creates `ggplot2`-graphics, as is confirmed by looking at [its entry in `CRAN`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wq/index.html). That means the information on [this page](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Axes_(ggplot2)/) should help you adjust the tick marks as you see fit.

I hope this helps. If it doesn't, then please provide a minimum working example, and I'll see what I can do with that.